# Is it possible to create interactive pages in epub format?

Tags: windows, android, epub, interactive

As part of a school project, I'm trying to create a small interactive e-booklet using the EPUB(3) format. It needs be readable (and "interactable") on both a Windows and Android reader.

I'm having no luck at all getting interactive pages to work on *any* reader. I've tried both HTML5 + JavaScript as well as SVG interactive pages, and though these work perfectly fine in browsers on both Windows and Android, any given epub reader will either render interactive pages as blank, will throw an error, will display non-SVG elements only, or will pretend the page doesn't exist at all. The only reader that will play ball whatsoever is an add-on for Firefox (epub-catalog)!

What gives? Am I making some mistake? I've Googled exhaustively, but I'm only finding sparse and conflicting information on whether or not it's even possible.

1. Is it possible to create interactive pages with EPUB3, whether via SVG or HTML5/JavaScript?
2. Which (if any) readers for Windows and Android will support this interactivity?

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no stand alone e-Readers that support EPUB3 quite yet. The exception might be the iPad which I heard does support some features, however I have not checked that.

If you could further define what you mean by "interactive" there might be some options to help, however most likely what you are trying to achieve using EPUB2 is just not possible and it might be a simple matter of waiting until support for EPUB3 becomes wide spread.